# Django - Edit referer when redirect

Tags: python, django

I'm using django3.1 with python3.6

I want to add a referer when redirecting URL. I'm using this code now, however, there is noting in referer.

```
response = HttpResponseRedirect(target_url)
response.set_cookie('name', name, max_age=9999, domain=None, samesite='None', secure=True)
response['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'https://example.com'
return response
```

Is there any problem with my code? or it is impossible to add referer?

Comment: You are adding a `HTTP_REFERRER` in the header of the *response*. It will not do anything in the header of the request that is triggered by the redirect.

Comment: I get your point now. So, there is no method to add referer when redirect?